# Include SQL Server database in application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have developed a c# application connected to a SQL Server 2008 database, and I want to make a project install.  How can I include my database in the application without having to have SQL Server 2008 installed?

Comment: Are you discussing the embedded version of SQL server?

Comment: If you are speaking about the SQL 2008 Std. Edition, you can't do that. What you might want is to use Compact Edition.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. SQL CE 3.5 ships with SQL 2008. Here's the link:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5821

Comment: Just one question. Do you want to know, how you can 'install', I would prefere 'create' the DB on the clients DBMS, because the DBMS is a prerequisite? Or do you really  want to install the DBMS and then create the DB?

Comment: i want install my application that will be include my db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. you better use [SQL SERVER COMPACT EDITION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact), if you don't want to install sql server in client's system. Sql Server Compact edition enables you to create a local database that can be accessed without sql server. But using it you will not be able to use your application on networking.

Comment: ok i understand that using sql server compact edition we can't use a network application. It's possible with sql server express edition ?

Comment: yes it is. Read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165647(v=sql.90).aspx