# Include SQL database in .NET Console program without requiring client to have SQL?

Tags: sql, .net

I'm working on writing a .NET console program, and one of the things that it is planned to do is CRUD operations on a specific set of data.  I currently have that set up as a List, but I'm thinking a SQL database would be ideal.  Problem is, I don't want the end user to have to install a SQL server for this program.

I looked at the question [Include SQL Server database in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274636/include-sql-server-database-in-application), which suggested using SQL Server Compact Edition.  However, that is deprecated, and I would rather use something that isn't deprecated.  MySQL is my SQL server of choice, but if that's not the best for this program, I am perfectly fine looking at other solutions.

Is it possible to have a SQL database as part of my program without requiring a SQL server for the end user?  If so, how?

Comment: SQL database? Any special one in mind? (There are dozens of them.)

Comment: @jarlh I don't have a specific one in mind.  As I said in the question, MySQL is my SQL database of choice but if something else would work better I can use that.

Comment: [LocalDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc) is an option

Comment: Thanks @Steve.  LocalDB is exactly what I was looking for, and I didn't even know it existed until now!